# Elastic query group by

Tags: elasticsearch

I've started the process of learning ElasticSearch and I was wondering if somebody could help me shortcut the process by providing some examples of how I would a build couple of queries.

Here's my example schema...

```
PUT /sales/_mapping
{   
   "sale": {
      "properties": {
         "productCode: {"type":"string"},
         "productTitle": {"type": "string"},
         "quantity" : {"type": "integer"},
         "unitPrice" : {"type": double}
       }
   }
}

POST /sales/1
{"productCode": "A", "productTitle": "Widget", "quantity" : 5, "unitPrice":
5.50}
POST /sales/2
{"productCode": "B", "productTitle": "Gizmo", "quantity" : 10, "unitPrice": 1.10}
POST /sales/3
{"productCode": "C", "productTitle": "Spanner", "quantity" : 5, "unitPrice": 
9.00}
POST /sales/4
{"productCode": "A", "productTitle": "Widget", "quantity" : 15, "unitPrice": 
5.40}
POST /sales/5
{"productCode": "B", "productTitle": "Gizmo", "quantity" : 20, "unitPrice": 
1.00}
POST /sales/6
{"productCode": "B", "productTitle": "Gizmo", "quantity" : 30, "unitPrice": 
0.90}
POST /sales/7
{"productCode": "B", "productTitle": "Gizmo", "quantity" : 40, "unitPrice": 
0.80}
POST /sales/8
{"productCode": "C", "productTitle": "Spanner", "quantity" : 100, 
"unitPrice": 7.50}
POST /sales/9
{"productCode": "C", "productTitle": "Spanner", "quantity" : 200, 
"unitPrice": 5.50}
```

What query would I need to generate the following results?

a). Show the show the number of documents grouped by product code

```
Product code  Title    Count
A             Widget   2
B             Gizmo    4
C             Spanner  3
```

b).  Show the total units sold by product code, i.e.

```
Product code  Title    Total units sold
A             Widget   20
B             Gizmo    100
C             Spanner  305
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that using [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html), in particular [Terms Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). And it can be done in just one run, by including them within your query structure; in order to instruct ES to generate analytic data based in aggregations, you need to include the `aggregations` object (or `aggs`), and specify within it the type of aggregations you would like ES to run upon your data.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "productCode"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "units_sold": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "quantity"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By running that query, besides the resulting hits from your search (in this case we are doing a match all), and additional object will be included, within the response object, holding the corresponding resulting aggregations. For example

```
{
  ...
  "hits": {
    "total": 6,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [ ... ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group_by_product": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "b",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "units_sold": {
            "value": 60
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "a",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "units_sold": {
            "value": 20
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "c",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "units_sold": {
            "value": 5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I omitted some details from the response object for brevity, and to highlight the important part, which is within the `aggregations` object. You can see how the aggregated data consists of different buckets, each representing the distinct product types (identified by the `key` key) that were found within your documents, `doc_count` has the number of occurrences per product type, and the `unit_sold` object, holds the total **sum** of units sold per each of the product types.

One important thing to keep into consideration is that in order to perform aggregations on **string** or **text** fields, you need to enable the **fielddata** setting within your field mapping, as that setting is disabled by default on all text based fields. In order to update the mapping, for ex. of the product code field, you just need to to a PUT request to the corresponding mapping type within the index, for example

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/sales/sale/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "productCode": {
      "type": "string",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

(more [info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html) about the fielddata setting)

Comment: Superb answer. thanks!  By the way does ES support a paging model for returning a declared start/page size block of results from a much larger result set?

Comment: Yes, you can include a "from" (offset), and "size" (number of results returned) within your query, have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: I've just noticed that the example answer doesn't include both the 'productCode' and 'productTitle' fields

Comment: If you want to include the productTitle (fielddata has to be enabled on that field as well), you'll need to add an aggregation for it (similar to the productCode agg). Keep in mind that, as far as I know, the resulting buckets cannot contain additional fields, other than the key (value) of the field that was used for the aggregation, and any other inner aggregations (like the sum in the example) that are included in it.